# Numerical stability of division expression

Tags: c++, numeric

I stumbled across code like

```
double x,y = ...;
double n = sqrt(x*x+y*y);
if (n > 0)
{
   double d1 = (x*x)/n;
   double d2 = (x*y)/n;
}
```

and I am wondering about the numerical stability of such an expression for small values of `x` and `y`.

For both expressions, `lim (x->0, y->0) (...) = 0`, so from a mathematical point of view, it looks safe (the nominator O(x²) whereas the denominator is O(x)).

Nevertheless my question is: Are there any possible numerical problems with this code?

EDIT: If possible I'd like to avoid re-writing the expressions because `n` is actually used more than twice and to keep readability (it's relatively clear in the context what happens).

Comment: Please, define "numerical problems". As x and y are not used as divisors, should it matter what their value is?

Comment: of course they are. If x -> 0 and y-> 0, then n -> 0 which means we are dividing by a very small number.

Comment: You are using doubles. the expression x->0 cannot be expressed in a double. The precision is high, but not high enough. If x>0 and y>0, n can never be 0.

Comment: Look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145889/en-us

Comment: @KonstantinL: I don't believe this covers my questions. I am asking about division by small numbers, not comparison of floating point numbers.

Comment: @ThunderGr: This is true. The question is: If n>0 but very small, can d1 or d2 become "relatively large" (because of a division by a very small number)?

Comment: You are concerned that this might result in an overflow? Hm...In this specific code, if x and y are small enough then their sqrt is small enough as well. So, no, in this specific piece of code, you cannot have an overflow.

Comment: In order to verify it, just run it against the smallest numbers you can think. I checked an example with x and y being 0.0000001

Comment: @Philipp this is the subject called "loss of precision". It includes comparing (like n > 0 in your case) and division and some more stuff.

Comment: @Philipp `n` can't be "very small" in relation to `x` and `y`, given the way it is calculated.  Unless e.g. `x * x` results in `0.0` (which may be the case if `x` is very small: `1E-300 * 1E-300` is `0.0` on most machines).

Comment: @ThunderGr `0.0000001` is not very small; an IEEE `double` can represent numbers with full precision down to around `2.22507E-308`.  Below that, gradual underflow (with a significant loss of precision) intervenes down to around `4.94066E-324`, then you get `0.0`.

Comment: @ThunderGr I don't see how you could get overflow, but you could easily get `0.0` or an extreme loss of precision, even if neither `x` nor `y` were `0.0`.  I wouldn't consider getting `0.0` in such cases "stable".

Comment: @JamesKanze Of course James. This is why I suggested to try with the smallest practical number he is to encounter :)

Comment: @JamesKanze an overflow could occur if you divided a large number with a very very small number.

Comment: @JamesKanze The actual precision of the double depends on how many significant digits you have *before the decimal point*. So, you can get the maximum precision you are talking about, if we are talking about a number with zero significant digits before the decimal point.

Comment: @ThunderGr Yes.  But given the way `n` is calculated, I don't think that this case can occur.  `n` is the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle whose sides are `x` and `y`, and if I recall my high school maths correctly, the hypotenuse will always be greater than either of the two sides.  (Of course, if `x * x` or `y * y` underflows, all bets are off.)

Comment: @ThunderGr The actual precision of a `double` (barring gradual underflow) is fixed by its representation: an IEEE `double` has a precision of 2^52 (or around 16 decimal digits).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are very close to `DBL_MIN`, the calculations are
succeptible to underflow or extreme loss of precision: if `x` is
very close to `DBL_MIN`, for example `x * x` may be `0.0`, or
(for somewhat larger values) it may result in what is called
gradual underflow, with extreme loss of precision: e.g. with
IEEE double (most, if not all desktop and laptop PCs), `1E-300
* 1E-300` will be `0.0`.  Obviously, if this happens for both
* `x` and `y`, you'll end up with `n == 0.0`, even if `x` and
`y` are both positive.

In C++11, there is a function `hypot`, which will solve the
problem for `n`; if `x * x` is `0.0`, however, `d1` will still
be `0.0`; you'll probably get better results with `(x / n) * x`
(but I think that there still may be limit cases where you'll
end up with `0.0` or gradual underflow—I've not analyzed it sufficiently to be sure).  A better solution
would be to scale the data differently, to avoid such limit
cases.

Comment: Thanks! Fortunately, a value of zero wouldn't do any harm. Is it correct that there probably won't be a problem of getting an unexperienced large value for d1 or d2?

Comment: @Philipp I can't see one.  The hypotenuse of a triangle (`n`) is always larger than either of its sides, so `n` should always be larger than `x` or `y`.  Given this, I don't foresee any risk.

Comment: Without C++11, I'd use `hypot(x,y)=max(x,y)*sqrt(1+square(min(x,y)/max(x,y))`. When `min(x,y)/max(x,y)` underflows, the result is `max(x,y)*sqrt(1)` which is a very good approximation.

Comment: @MSalters Even without C++11, there's a good chance that `::hypot` will be in `<math.h>`, since it has been in C since 1999.  (Of course, if the C compiler corresponding to your version of C++ doesn't support C99...  The only case of this I know of is the compiler in Visual Studios, however.)  Otherwise, your expression is very close to the implementation given by Wikipedia.  (Alternatively: if you're on an Intel, and don't mind a bit of assembler, you can just use the extended precision it provides.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, VC++ always had `_hypot` and VS2012 has `std::hypot` so it's not too bad.